# Using automatically generated methods for public attributes vs creating methods for accessing private attributes

Tags: class, oop, attributes, raku

Let's say I have a class with several attributes but I only need some of them for object construction; the remaining attributes's values depend on these *public* attributes. However, I'd like to still access the remaining attributes's values with methods named after the attributes. From the top of my head, there are two options:

**First option:**

- Overload the `new` method. Or leave the `new` method as is, and instead use a `BUILD` submethod to both set the passed argument to the right attribute and set remaining attributes using this argument's value.

```
class Foo {
    has Int $.a;
    has Int $.b;
    has Int $.c;

    submethod BUILD(:$!a) {
        $!b = $!a ** 2;
        $!c = $!a ** 3;
    }
}
```

```
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b);   #=> Foo.new(a => 2, b => 4, c => 8)
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b).b; #=> 8
```

**Second option:**

Declare with `$.` only those attributes needed for object construction and modify the remaining attributes (declared with `$!`) with a `TWEAK` submethod after object construction. However, now I need to create accesor methods for these attributes.

```
class Bar {
    has Int $.a;
    has Int $!b;
    has Int $!c;

    submethod TWEAK {
        $!b = $!a ** 2;
        $!c = $!a ** 3;
    }

    method b { $!b }
    method c { $!c }
}
```

```
say Bar.new(:2a, :1b);   #=> Bar.new(a => 2)
say Bar.new(:2a, :1b).b; #=> 8
```

#### Questions

What's the *best* option? Are there any other options? What are the advantages/drawbacks for each option?

Comment: Considering that passing `b` and `c` parameters has no bearing on the object creation I find it a bit odd someone would find the `.perl` output of `Foo.new(a => 2, b => 4, c => 8)` acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps an "is accessible" trait on the attribute, that would automatically do option 2  on private attributes?  I've been in that place many times.

Comment: @ugexe, I've seen too many times so I wasn't surprised. However, as you say, it gives the wrong impression about those attributes accessible at object construction.

Comment: @Elizabeth Mattijsen, do a new trait that would create an acessor method for an otherwise private attribute, right?! It sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: FWIW, I thought that was going to be easy, but this is going to require some tweaking of the internals.  Specfically, the Attribute.has_accessor` method now means that a public accessor should be created **and** that you can set that attribute with `.new`: those two meanings will have to be split.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen *do you mean a... Edit: BTW, Holli shared a similar idea (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569847/10824322).

Comment: No, the other way around: a private method (hence not settable with `.new`) that will have an accessor created for it anyway.  This is I think the most common case, and which I've encountered a few times myself.

Comment: Added an issue to the problem-solving repo: https://github.com/perl6/problem-solving/issues/145

Comment: Implemented it and put it in a PR: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/3404

Comment: It's now in core as `is built`: `$!a is built` now allows you to have the private accessor set with `.new`, but without creating an accessor for it.  And `$.a is built(False)` will create an accessor for the attribute, but will inhibit setting it with `.new`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I'd go nice and simple :

```
class Foo { 
    has Int $.a; 
    has Int $!b = $!a ** 2; 
    has Int $!c = $!a ** 3;
    method b { $!b }
    method c { $!c }
}
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b); #=>  Foo.new(a => 2)
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b).b; #=> 4
```

Just use the default constructor and default values for the attributes and add a couple of basic read methods. The default constructor only updates public attributes so if you try and override `b` or `c` this is ignored.

If you wanted you could add a `BUILD` submethod to error if someone tries and sets them.

A good point raised in the comments for this case (and possibly the final use case) doing it like this :

```
class Foo { 
    has Int $.a; 
    method b() is pure { $!a ** 2 }
    method c() is pure { $!a ** 3 }
}
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b); #=>  Foo.new(a => 2)
say Foo.new(:2a, :1b).b; #=> 4
```

Depending on the complexity of the calculation you may want to use the `is cached` trait too.

Comment: I'd probably even go with `class Foo { has Int $.a; method b { $!a ** 2 }; method c { $!a ** 3 } }` it's simpler, even if it technically adds some overhead (though minor if just a simple math op, and if it's major, `is cached` could be added to speed things up).

Comment: I don't mind this answer. The only thing I would add is if `$!a` is necessary for the object to be constructed, then the `is required` trait should be used with it IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I read an article a couple of weeks ago that talked about this ambiguity between the constructor arguments of a class and its public interface but I cannot find it anymore.

But I am thinking you could leverage `FALLBACK`.

```
class Bar {
    has Int $.a;
    has Int $!b;
    has Int $!c;

    submethod TWEAK {
        $!b = $!a ** 2;
        $!c = $!a ** 3;
    }

    method FALLBACK( $name ) {
        self.^attributes.first( *.name eq "\$!$name" ).?get_value(self);
    }
}

say Bar.new(:2a);
say Bar.new(:2a).c;
```

That's kinda hacky though, and costly since the attribute lookups have to go though `FALLBACK` and introspection. What would be nice to have is a trait that would create an accessor but have no effect on the constructor. Something like

```
class Bar {
    has Int $.a;
    has Int $.b is shady; # or whatever name
    has Int $.c is shady;
}
```

But I am not aware such a thing exists.

Comment: I'd have liked to read the article you mention. I think I'll steer away from using `FALLBACK` since the class that prompted me to ask this question is pretty simple and thus using metaprogramming for it would be a bit excessive in this case.